# How to position an xypic diagram within body of text

Tags: positioning, xy-pic

I have an `xypic` diagram that I want to have within the body of text (`article` class). The .tex file looks like this at the relevant place:

```
\section{A Framework}

What we have now is a picture that looks like the following:

\xymatrixcolsep{3pc}
\begin{figure}
\centerline{\xymatrix{
*+[F-]\txt{`The World'}\ar[d] & & *+[F-]{\text{Models}} \ar[d]\\
*+[F-]\txt{Propositions $p, ...$}\ar[d] & & *+[F-]{\txt{Sentences $\phi, ...$}} \ar[d]\\
*+[F-]\txt{Informal Theory $T_I$} \ar[d] \ar[rr]_*+[F-:<8pt>]{\small{\emph{Formalisation}}}  & & *+[F-]{\txt{Formal Theory $T_F$}} \ar[d]\\
*+[F-]{\text{Informal Beliefs}}\ar[d] &  & *+[F-]{\txt{Formal Properties}} \ar[d] \\
*+[F-,]{\bf{e.g. Semantic Realism}} \ar@{-}@/^6pc/[uuuu] \ar@{.}[rr] & & *+[F-,]{\bf{e.g. Categoricity}} \ar@{-}@/_6pc/[uuuu] & \\
}}
\end{figure}

There are such things as informal mathematical theories, consisting of purely mathematical propositions in natural language, which are in turn about mathematical reality (or, `the world') in some sense.
```

I want the diagram to be where it seems to be placed in the code, but when I typeset it just sticks to the top of the page, before the section 'A Framework' even begins. How do I move it? Can't seem to find any advice.

Comment: `figure`s float, try `center` instead.

Comment: Thanks! So simple. I did search the forums already to avoid duplicating but couldn't find anything. Tip to self: use better search terms.